# regular expression in Ruby with parentheses and match

Tags: ruby

In Ruby,

```
x = "this is a test".match(/(\w+) (\w+)/)
puts x[0], x[1], x[2]
```

why is the output

```
this is
this 
is
```

Comment: What did you expect instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing special is going on here. You have the pattern

```
(\w+) (\w+)
```

namely **two words separated by a space**. That would be `"this is"` in your example (since we start looking for matches from the beginning of the string). The full match goes into the zeroth element of the return value, in your case `x[0]`.

Now parentheses capture matches. The first left parenthesis starts at the first word, namely `"this"` so that value goes into `x[1]`. The second left parenthesis starts a group that matches the word `"is"`, which will be captured into `x[2]`.

Again, nothing special. This is how regular expression matching and grouping work in many, many languages.

Comment: And I'll just add that if the asker was expecting multiple matches, he should use `x = "this is a test".scan(/(\w+) (\w+)/)`, which, instead of stopping after one match, will find every match in the string and return an array.